# Dense set in positive real

Tags: general-topology

i, Let $f=x^2+2x$ be a quadratic polynomial and $\mathcal{R}_f$ be its range.

Denote $\mathcal{A}_{i+1}$ be the set of real numbers that lie in $\mathcal{R}_f$ get from finding roots of equation $f(x)=n_i$ where $n_i\in\mathcal{A}_i$, $\mathcal{A}_0=\mathbb{Z}\cap \mathcal{R}_f$.

Let $A=\mathbb{Z}\cup (\bigcup_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathcal{A}_i)$ and $B=\{x|x\ge 0,x\in A\}$. Is $B$ dense in $\mathbb{R^+}$ ?

ii, Find all quadratic polynomials $f$ such that $B$ is dense in $\mathbb{R^+}$.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What is the source of this problem? Have you tried working on it yourself? What success have you had so far?

Comment: I found this when I was trying to solve a nice functional equation. I think that this claim is so nice (if it's true !?) :)